# MVC Extension Method Not Able To Return Data to View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am fairly new to MVC and trying to do my first extension method for formatting phone numbers.  I had all the logic previously in the view which I am learning defeats the principles of MVC.  So for code reuse and following MVC standard practice I am attempting to do this extension method.

```
namespace Data.CustomHtmlHelper
{
public static class CustomerHelperHelper
 {
    public static string PhoneNumber(this HtmlHelper helper, string value)
    {
        value = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"\D")
            .Replace(value, string.Empty);
        value = value.TrimStart('1');
        if (value.Length == 7)
            return Convert.ToInt64(value).ToString("###-####");
        if (value.Length == 10)
            return Convert.ToInt64(value).ToString("###-###-####");
        if (value.Length > 10)
            return Convert.ToInt64(value)
                .ToString("###-###-#### " + new String('#', (value.Length - 10)));
        return value;
    }
 }
}
```

This example is giving me an error message "that the value cannot be null".

Try Number 2:

```
     public static string PhoneNumber(this HtmlHelper helper, string value)
    {

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            if (value != null && value.Length == 7)
                return Convert.ToInt64(value).ToString("###-####");
            if (value != null && value.Length == 10)
                return Convert.ToInt64(value).ToString("###-###-####");
            if (value != null && value.Length > 10)
                return Convert.ToInt64(value)
                    .ToString("###-###-#### " + new String('#', (value.Length - 10)));
        }

        else if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        {
            return Convert.ToInt64(value).ToString("###-####");
        }
        return value;
    }
```

This will will not return the correct value for the phone number in the View all that is there is "-".

Try Number 3:

```
       public static string PhoneNumber(this HtmlHelper helper, string value)
    {
        if (value != null && value.Length > 6)
            return "Invalid Phone Number";
        if (value != null && value.Length == 7)
            return Convert.ToInt64(value).ToString("###-####");
        if (value != null && value.Length == 10)
            return Convert.ToInt64(value).ToString("###-###-####");
        if (value != null && value.Length > 10)
            return Convert.ToInt64(value)
                .ToString("###-###-#### " + new String('#', (value.Length - 10)));
        return value;
    }
```

This doesn't return anything in the view.

Using the same view for all.

```
@using Data.CustomHtmlHelper

  <div class="col-md-4">                             
     @Html.PhoneNumber(Model.phone_no)
  </div>
```

Comment: Just put a breakpoint in your code to figure out why this is being returned by the extension method.

Comment: Sounds that you want to use custom HTML helper, I suggest you using `MvcHtmlString` e.g. `public static MvcHtmlString PhoneNumber` & returning a HTML string (e.g. `return MvcHtmlString.Create(value.ToString());`)

Comment: In try #3, this line is incorrect - `if (value != null && value.Length > 6)` -> it should be `if (value != null && value.Length <= 6)`.  You are falling through your if statement here.  Also...what if value is 8 or 9 in length?